# I'd like to know if these claims are true or false before attempting to prove them.

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, martingales

let $(X_n)_{n \geq0}$ be a uniformly integrable martingale

does it converge in $L^1$ ? $L^2$ ? almost surely ?

I don't want a proof, I just want to know which claims are true so I can attempt proving them myself.

Comment: Why do you need to know whether something is true to attempt to prove it? If it's not true, you'll fail. Furthermore, if you're lucky, perhaps along the way to failing, you'll develop clues to how to disprove it.

Comment: @LeeMosher From my experience, you can waste a lot of time trying to prove something that is false. It's discouraging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A martingale is uniformly integrable if and only if it converges in $L^1$.

A uniformly integrable martingale converges almost surely.

For convergence in $L^2$ we need to know a bit more. (for example the martingale being bounded in $L^2$ is sufficient)